# NRF24L01+ (RF Module) for Smart Home Device Communcation

Tags: rf, communication, bluetooth, wifi, zigbee

A while back I purchased [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00O9O868G) RF modules (NRF24L01+) and I am starting a project using them; the project is implementing a network of smart devices as slaves connected to a central wifi-enabled hub (Esp8266 or Raspberry PI, most likely). I've done some research on wifi, BT, and Zigbee-based sensor/slave networks, but I am having trouble seeing where these RF modules fit.

Specifically, I'm having some trouble understanding if these RF modules can be used in a similar way to Wifi, BT, or Zigbee-based home automation setups. I can't find many resources for implementing a slave network with this kind of RF communication module nor many commercial products that appear to use these, and my question is: do these modules have any technical barriers that would not allow them to be implemented in or that would make them less-suited for this application?

Comment: Just a quick comment until I have time for a longer answer: these radios are fine and I use them myself for my little home automation setup including a motorized curtain, some sensors and a handful of wirelessly controlled LED strips. Other than that your question is a bit broad and it is not completely clear what you are asking for.

Comment: I will narrow the scope a bit and clarify what I am asking, thanks for the info.

Comment: Actually those (and their clones) are used a lot could be very suitable, and are in some ways the technical ancestor of BLE.  What's conceptually missing is that you have to write your own protocol to run on them - the module is just the radio, data slicer, packet buffer, etc.  You have to decide how you want your network to work and then implement it.  The larger issue for the moment is that you don't have a question which can be specifically and concisely answered as a matter of fact rather than opinion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one scenario that I can think of when it makes sense to use these modules: To have a simple inexpensive reliable short-range wireless communication, especially unidirectional one, up and running quickly with Arduino libraries. Especially for small projects.

For anything more complex, especially with mobile phones, there's Bluetooth Low Energy. If you want to make a high-volume product for simple wireless communication, it'll be better to use an inexpensive RF transceiver like 
RFM75W.

Comment: In what sense is an RFM75 different from an NRF24L01+?

Comment: Its better for a product because of the lower cost, smaller size and SMD pads in a module.